# Hashing payload data when adding a new user in a Facebook Custom Audiences

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

i need an help with the API to add a user in a custom audience.
Looking at the doc it seems not clear if it has to be hashed every single attribute of the `payload.data` key or not.

On the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/users/v2.9) it seems like the hash in not required but in this other article (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api) seems like each one of them has to be hashed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to hash everything apart from external identifiers, see this part of the doc:

> You must hash your data as SHA256; we don't support other hashing
>   mechanisms. This is required for all data except External Identifiers.
>   Before hashing, normalize your data. Only First name FN and Last Name
>   LN support special characters and non-Roman alphabet. For best match
>   results, provide the Roman alphabet translation with no special
>   characters.

External identifiers are just `extern_id` which isn't applicable to most people anyway.

I'd recommend using one our our SDKs if possible as we handle all of the hashing for you. For example:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\CustomAudienceMultiKey;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields;

$users = array(
  array('ExternId123', 'FirstName', 'test2@example.com', 'LastName1'),
  array('ExternId456', 'FirstNameTest', '', 'LastNameTest'),
  array('ExternId789', '', 'test3@example.com', 'LastNameTest'),
);

$schema = array(
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::EXTERN_ID,
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::FIRST_NAME,
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::EMAIL,
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::LAST_NAME,
);

$audience = new CustomAudienceMultiKey('<CUSTOM_AUDIENCE_ID>');
$audience->addUsers($users, $schema);
```